# setInterval does not in React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I made a React component that can scroll content to page top when necessary, if you look at the code sandbox example, the "GO Top" button shows up if scroll down a bit, if you click it, the page will scroll to top, and if you try to scroll down back, it alway bring you to page top. The reason is the timer is not cleared because the intervalId is always null. specifically, if you check out line #20, the intervalId is always null, I guess it might be related to closure, but I cannot fix it. please help.

Thanks!

code is posted below, [codesanbox example is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-bash-ei9ms)

```
import React from "react";

const GoTop = ({ scrollStepInPx, delayInMs }) => {
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = React.useState(null);
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 200) {
        setPosition(true);
      } else {
        setPosition(false);
      }
    });
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []);

  const onScrollStep = () => {
    if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
      console.log(intervalId); //always null
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      return;
    }
    window.scroll(0, window.pageYOffset - scrollStepInPx);
  };

  const scrollToTop = () => {
    const id = setInterval(onScrollStep, delayInMs);
    setIntervalId(() => id);
  };

  const renderGoTopIcon = () => {
    if (position) {
      return (
        <button className="go-top" onClick={scrollToTop} type="button">
          Go Top
        </button>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };

  return <>{renderGoTopIcon()}</>;
};

export default GoTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it work like this, this posts helped.
https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/

```
import React from "react";

const GoTop = ({ scrollStepInPx, delayInMs }) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 200) {
        setPosition(true);
      } else {
        setPosition(false);
      }
    });
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []);

  const scrollToTop = () => {
    let intervalId;
    //move the event handle here, NOT use hooked state variable intervalId
    const onScrollStep = () => {
      if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        return;
      }
      window.scroll(0, window.pageYOffset - scrollStepInPx);
    };

    intervalId = setInterval(onScrollStep, delayInMs);
  };

  const renderGoTopIcon = () => {
    if (position) {
      return (
        <button className="go-top" onClick={scrollToTop} type="button">
          Go Top
        </button>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };

  return <>{renderGoTopIcon()}</>;
};

export default GoTop;
```